# Getting 404 NOT FOUND on Service Deployment on kubernetes/istio

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I created yaml files and deployed the service on kubernetes and istio. Everything looks fine but when I test the service it gives a 404 NOT FOUND. I am not sure if I missed something. Does anyone have any solutions for this or where I might be wrong? Here are the yaml files:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: login-register-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - webapp-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /loginregister
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8080
        host: login-register-service
```

The above code is virtual-service code.
This is the web-service code.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: login-register-service
  labels:
    app: login-register-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
  selector:
    app: login-register-service
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: login-register
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: login-register-service
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: login-register-service
        image: {ImageName}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

The error message which I got on postman is
404 NOT FOUND

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-22T18:15:28.206+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/loginregister/sms/auth"
}
```

Comment: How are you testing it? CURL or Browser? How does the Gateway look like?

Comment: I tested it using CURL. The Gateway shows 404 NOT FOUND. But on the gke and kubernetes it shows OK. So is there an issue with the yaml files?

Comment: Are you configuring it with a Gateway resource to allow traffic into the Gateway and are you directing the traffic to the services using VirtualServices?

Comment: Your path in vs is /loginregister, try to change it to /loginregister/sms/auth or add rewrite to /loginregister/sms/auth as mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite).

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of gateway 'webapp-gateway' ?